# conflicting type for funct in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to run the code below and i am getting the error messages below.

Program:

```
int main()
{
    int (*res)[3],i;
    res=func();


}

int (*func())[3]
{
    static int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    return arr;
}
```

Error:

```
PointerTo1D.c: In function ‘main’:
PointerTo1D.c:6:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  res=func();
     ^
PointerTo1D.c: At top level:
PointerTo1D.c:11:7: error: conflicting types for ‘func’
 int (*func())[3]
   ^
PointerTo1D.c:6:6: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘func’ was here 
 res=func();
```

Could someone please help me out here???

Comment: need prototype before main.

Comment: Whatever you do: **do not add a cast**. *The warning message text could be better ... maybe "conversion from integer to pointer in assignment"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a pointer to an array with 3 elements of int

`int (*func())[3]`: func is a function which returns a pointer to array with 3 elements of int

Because there is no prototype for function `func()` you got:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'func'
    res=func();
```

which means that compiler use default prototype `int func()`.

There is next warning:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     res=func();
```

because default prototype is used, compiler assumes that function `func()` returns `int` which is than assigned as a pointer to `res` which is the pointer

When code for function `func()` is reached you get error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'func'
 int (*func())[3]
```

Solution is to provide proper prototype before `main`.

```
int (*func())[3];

int main()
{
 ...
}
```

**Update:** There is also warning:

```
warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
     static int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

It is better to use:

```
static int arr[3][3]={{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code to

```
int** func()     //change here
{
    static int arr[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    return arr;
}
```

and

```
int** func();   //forward declaration

int main()
{
    int ** res = NULL,i = 0;   //change here
    res=func();

    return 0;
}
```

Any function you call from your `main()` should *either* be defined before `main()` *or* atleast have a forward declaration before `main()` so that the comipler has a way to know the function signature before the function is used (called).

Note: Usually, it's not a good practice to use `static` for this purpose. Dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`/`calloc()`) is designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `func()` at least needs to be declared prior to where `main()` is calling it. (to get rid of `conflicting types for ‘func’` and `previous implicit declaration of ‘func’ ...`)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the reason for this is that otherwise you're trying to store an `int*` in an `int**`, so you're trying to change the type. That's what causing the error. EDIT: Wait, is it actualy?

Comment: If you are providing a functions definition above main() than you don't need declaration

Comment: Prototype `int (*func())[3];` is enough.

Comment: 1. A pointer is not an array. 2. Old-style declarations are deprecated. Suggest using a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to return a pointer do like this :

```
(int **)func() {
 ...
 return arr;
 }
```

Then define res like this :

```
int ** res;
res = func();
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function is called without a declaration being visible, it is assumed to be old-style declared, with external linkage, and returning an `int` in C89:

```
extern int func();
```

The empty parentheses (an old-style declaration) mean: No argument checking required, function takes fixed number of default-promoted arguments.

In C99, implicit declarations have been removed, Gcc warns about them by default, but sticks to the old behaviour, probably for backward compatibility. They can be turned into errors for example with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`, or `gcc -std=gnu89 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration` if you want to stick to GNU89 (what I suspect was specified from the warnings given).

To fix the problem, the function needs at least to be declared before use:

```
int (*func())[3];

int main() {
    func();
}
```

This still uses old-style declarations, marked obsolescent in all C standards, I'd suggest using prototypes to ensure argument checking:

```
int (*func(void))[3];

int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```